# Limit number of MapEntries in Map: Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I need to have a Map that stores exactly 100 key-value pairs.
If, while adding a new pair, the number of pairs exceeds 100, I want the oldest pair to be deleted and latest one added in.

Somewhat like a [`Queue`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) with only 100 slots.

This is the current map,

```dart
Map<String, String> r = {
   rId: DateTime.now().toString() // Id is key, created time is value
}
```

I believe we can achieve this with some implementation of [`LinkedHashMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html).
I do not understand how. Any help is appreciated

Comment: you can just extend map class and override the add/remove method, and keep a counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind adding a package [quiver](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) has a `LruMap` which is  exactly what you are describing. See its docs [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/LruMap-class.html).

LRU stands for Least recently used so the items will be evicted from the map as you describe.

Comment: If you don't want to add a dependency you could just extract the code for the LruMap. But is probable that the quiver packages is already being used by one of your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into @croxx5f solution and found it unnecessarely kinda complex

Here is a simplified version that does what you need:

```dart
  final _optimizedMap = <int, String>{};
  final items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  final entries = items.map((e) => MapEntry(e, "item $e"));

  for (final e in entries) {
    _optimizedMap.remove(e.key); // removing so that items are inserted lastly, indicating that it has been used.
    _optimizedMap[e.key] = e.value;
  }

  final excess = _optimizedMap.length - 300; // <-- change to max length.
  if (excess > 0) {
    final excessKeys = _optimizedMap.keys.take(excess).toList();
    for (final k in excessKeys) {
      _optimizedMap.remove(k);
    }
  }
```

You can also use it as an extension for an easier usage:

```dart
/// Usage
final _optimizedMap = {};
_optimizedMap.optimizedAdd([MapEntry("key" ,"value")], 100);

/// Extension
extension LRUMap<K, V> on Map<K, V> {
  void optimizedAdd(Iterable<MapEntry<K, V>> entries, int max) {
    final map = this;

    for (final e in entries) {
      map.remove(e.key); // removing so that items are inserted lastly, indicating that it has been used.
      map[e.key] = e.value;
    }

    final excess = map.length - max;
    if (excess > 0) {
      final excessKeys = map.keys.take(excess).toList();
      for (final k in excessKeys) {
        map.remove(k);
      }
    }
  }
}
```